# Optimal way to pipe many files to Gnu Parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, pipe

I need some help in optimizing gnu parallel when the input data is contained in many files, which must be concatenated together and piped into several different commands, each to be run in parallel.

I am parsing data from an archive whose contents are contained in many files. The goal is to parse different data types into files by type for the whole archive. To accomplish this I am concatenating the files together and piping them to each parsing command. The parser accepts data on stdin and takes as an argument the data type to parse (e.g 'parser type1' to parse data of type1, etc.)

At the moment I have something like this:

```
parallel --xapply ::: \ 
   'cat datadir/*.dat | parser type1 > type1.txt' \ 
   'cat datadir/*.dat | parser type2 > type2.txt' \ 
   'cat datadir/*.dat | parser type3 > type3.txt'
```

But this requires concatenation of the data several times, which is slow and seems unnecessary costly. Plus my understanding is that there is a throughput limit on a pipe. Is there an better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit complex but it avoids reading `datadir/*.dat` more than once, it uses fifos instead of temporary files.

```
# Example parser
parser() { cat | grep "$@"; }
# Make function visible to GNU Parallel
export -f parser

types="type1 type2 type3"
# Create fifos: myfifo-type1 myfifo-type2 myfifo-type3
parallel mkfifo myfifo-{} ::: $types
# Send datadir/*.dat to 'parser type1', 'parser type2', 'parser type3'
# send output to myfifo-type1 myfifo-type2 myfifo-type3
cat datadir/*.dat |
  parallel -j0 --pipe --tee parser {} '>' myfifo-{} ::: $types &
# Read from the fifos
parallel --xapply echo :::: myfifo*
rm myfifo*
```

It is a bit unclear what command you want in the final `--xapply`. Maybe what you are looking for is simply sending the same input to `parser` with different parameters:

```
cat datadir/*.dat |
  parallel -j0 --pipe --tee parser {} '>' output-{} ::: $types
```

which is much simpler than the `mkfifo` setup above.

Pipes/fifos are very fast (>2 GB/s) and there is no limit to the amount of data you can put through those. They avoid that data ever hit the disk.

Comment: That is precisely it, I wanted to send the same input to the parser with different parameters. I omitted the explicit command because I'd already gone through the effort of creating a list of the complete commands to execute (before thinking about using parallel). I somehow missed the --tee option and must have misunderstood the warnings in the man page about --pipe. Thanks.

Comment: I can see it is not really clear that the limitation in `--pipe` does not apply when using `--tee`.